# C# RichTextBox новая строка

Tags: c#, winforms

Возник мелкий вопрос. Как создавать новые строки пользователю при написании текста в сабже? Enter не работает. Пытался изменить свойство Multiline, но почему-то не сработало.

Comment: Может, покажете код?

Comment: @VladD, а что там показывать? Создан на форме объект richtextbox, в конструкторе формы прописано свойство: richtextbox.Multiline = true;

Comment: А [`AcceptsReturn`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn.aspx)?

Comment: @VladD чувак, миллион благодарностей. Правда, такого свойства нет, есть более общее AcceptsTab, ну да ладно.

Answer (score 2):

Вашу задачу хорошо решает пример из статьи [TextBox.AcceptsReturn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn.aspx) на MSDN:

```
public void CreateMyMultilineTextBox()
{
    // Create an instance of a TextBox control.
    TextBox textBox1 = new TextBox();

    // Set the Multiline property to true.
    textBox1.Multiline = true;
    // Add vertical scroll bars to the TextBox control.
    textBox1.ScrollBars = ScrollBars.Vertical;
    // Allow the RETURN key to be entered in the TextBox control.
    textBox1.AcceptsReturn = true;
    // Allow the TAB key to be entered in the TextBox control.
    textBox1.AcceptsTab = true;
    // Set WordWrap to true to allow text to wrap to the next line.
    textBox1.WordWrap = true;
    // Set the default text of the control.
    textBox1.Text = "Welcome!";
}
```

В данном примере для многострочного `TextBox` включается не только `Enter`, но ещё и `Tab`, плюс добавляется вертикальный скроллбар и перенос слов. Таким образом, имеем хороший набор значений свойств многострочного [TextBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx). Приведу также описание этих [свойств](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox_properties%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) из MSDN:

- [Multiline](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/12w624ff(v=vs.110).aspx): Возвращает или задает значение, указывающее, является ли это multiline - TextBox элемент управления.
- [ScrollBars](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.scrollbars(v=vs.110).aspx): Возвращает или задает, какие полосы прокрутки должны отображаться в multiline - TextBox элемент управления.
- [AcceptsReturn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.acceptsreturn(v=vs.110).aspx): Возвращает или задает значение, указывающее, осуществляет ли нажатие клавиши ВВОД в многополосном элементе управления TextBox создание новой строки текста или активирует кнопку по умолчанию для формы.
- [AcceptsTab](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.acceptstab(v=vs.110).aspx): Получает или задает значение, указывающее, что происходит при нажатии клавиши TAB в многострочном элементе управления: вводится знак табуляции в текстовом поле или фокус ввода в форме перемещается к следующему элементу управления в последовательности переходов.
- [WordWrap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.wordwrap(v=vs.110).aspx): Показывает, переносятся ли автоматически в начало следующей строки слова текста по достижении границы многострочного текстового поля.